# Codes Work in USA but not in China?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using A/Studio 2.2
My code unpacks a bundle of LatLng-parameters from a preceeding activity and displays the corresponding G/Map, works well in USA. Loved it. In USA, I used Android 6.
I am in China now, I have downloaded Play Store, Google Maps, Gmail etc and installed them on a local popular low-end phone "vivo-v3m". When I installed G/Maps, a message flashed quickly across Android saying GPS is off and to authorize Google to download something to use Google maps, which I did. In China I am using Android 5.1 
G/maps works well after that but my app is still not working. 
I strongly suspect I have to include or compile some G/Map APIs into the dependencies in the gradle.
Before I start debugging why the code doesn't work here, I need to know whether it is some Google APIs I have to download to use G/Maps.

Answer (score 0):

**Google services is now blocked in China**. So Google map is not working in china. use **Baidu Maps for china**

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same problem before while developing for a Chinese website and came across Baidu maps. After doing some analysis I found few links that give explanation on Baidu maps in English and steps to implement it. I hope it helps you.

http://www.maplandia.com/china/fujian/fuqing/baidu/

Examples of baidu map api :
[http://api.map.baidu.com/library/MarkerClusterer/1.2/examples/simple.htm](https://api.map.baidu.com/library/MarkerClusterer/1.2/examples/simple.htm)

Baidu Maps Javascript API Document:
https://qianggan.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/baidu-maps-javascript-api-document/
[enter link description here](https://qianggan.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/baidu-maps-javascript-api-document/)

Comment: Thx for the links, I will  try them. I'll share the results with u soon.